# How to hide a specific out-of-the-box checkbox from the ribbon?

Tags: 2010, ribbon

I'm trying to remove the `Open in new window` checkbox, in the link tabs of a rich text editor.

I tried:

```
<HideCustomAction Id="Hide.Ribbon.Link.Link.Behavior.PopUp"
                  Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
                  HideActionId="Ribbon.Link.Link.Behavior.PopUp"/>
```

But the checkbox is still there.

What is the correct syntax to hide this checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<fulminating against='Microsoft'>
```

I finally found the solution. Thanks to the article [Removing objects from the SharePoint ribbon](http://www.3guysonsharepoint.com/?p=778), I understood that I have to overwrite the existing definition instead of trying to hide it.

So in my very specific case, I have to write this xml:

```
  <CustomAction Id="Hide.Ribbon.Link.Link.Behavior.PopUp"
                Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"               >
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Link.Link.Behavior.PopUp"/>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
```

This has the effect of hiding the existing control.

```
</fulminating>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms414790.aspx) for HideCustomAction closes the tag with `</HideCustomAction>`. Maybe that's all that's missing.

Else, you could try using [Security trimming](http://www.codeovereasy.com/2013/04/security-trimming-the-sharepoint-ribbon/) (so that the option only appears for uses with certain permissions levels) or `TrimById()` (see "Hide a single Button on Ribbon" section of [this forum](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/10/24/hide-ribbon-buttons-sharepoint-2010-programmatically/)).

Comment: It's xml... so the syntax are equivalent. Just to be sure, I tested. With no suprise, the behavior is equivalent. And I would like to do this declarative only.